# PHP CURL to upload multiple images in parallel

Tags: php, curl

i'm using this cURL wrapper https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/src/Curl/Curl.php

to upload images, is working perfectly if I upload a photo without multi-curl, but when trying to upload photos in parallel mode with multi-curl, the request headers are missing this part.

```
 Expect: 100-continue
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------5a6bd9bcdf53e647
```

Tried debugging and seems the whole process of preparing the curl, curl child of multi-curl, and file object are the same.

I assume the CURLFile is modifying the curl headers with the appropriate values, but seems to get lost when using multi-curl ..

Comment: Imo there is no need for a cURL wrapper and just a waste of space and computing time. I think you don't need a multi-curl object. In the end you're just sending POST data and I think it's possible to just append multiple `CURLFile` objects to the same post data array. Check http://php.net/manual/de/curlfile.construct.php

Comment: Are you using the 'multi' methods of that [php-curl-class wrapper - it does know about the 'multi' file variants but has different methods](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/src/Curl/Curl.php)? Original cURL example: [Uploading multiple files using PHP via curl](http://iswwwup.com/t/7a7f6747792a/uploading-multiple-files-using-php-via-curl.html). fyi, I  would be tempted to use the simple cURL method and run them in separate shell processes. i.e. Let the O/S look after all the 'interesting' stuff.

Comment: @Charlotte & Ryan, thank you I will try with multiple files in one request.

Comment: Does not work, it gives a 503 unavailable error, I suppose is expecting only one file / request.

Comment: Managed to get multiple files to upload by re-initiating the class before the multi-request, some prior setting must be interfering with the multi-curl settings